# Fetch Process instance Id from camunda libraries

Tags: java, spring-boot, camunda, camunda-modeler

How to fetch the process instance id's basis on the parameters which were sent from the pojo request to camunda workflow engine.
By using Java spring boot

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to find a running process instance by a value of a process variable?

```
runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery()
  .variableValueEquals("variableName", "expected value")
  .list()
```